# Difference between kernel 4.15.0-42-generic and 4.15.0-29-generic in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: grub2, 18.04, kernel, cuda

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and when I check **Advanced Options for Ubuntu** in the GRUB menu, I found there are two options

- ubuntu 4.15.0-42-generic
- ubuntu 4.15.0-29-generic

What is the difference between these kernel versions and which is preferred in general to use?

I installed CUDA and first it was working fine **only** with 4.15.0-29-generic and I was getting an error when I used Ubuntu 4.15.0-42-generic (which was the default option for my Ubuntu in the GRUB menu).

To solve the problem I had to reinstall the kernel using

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic
```

I would like to know what exactly is happening with the two kernel versions. If anyone can give me an idea of what happened, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. How did you install CUDA? Did you use `apt`?

Comment: Hi , I just followed the exact procedures in nvidia site [https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html] . I installed cuda following runfile installation

Comment: Also, how did you install the nvidia drivers?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you installed CUDA manually instead of using `apt-get` or `apt`.

When you install drivers and other stuff manually and the kernel gets updated using `apt` or `apt-get`, `apt` and `apt-get` won't know what needs to be updated unless it is DKMS.

To avoid this problem, you can use `apt` or `apt-get` to do the installation instead of installing stuff manually.

Run the following commands to install using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit nvidia-nsight
```

If you installed your nvidia drivers manually as well, please comment to let me know and I will add additional instructions.

Please post any errors, thanks.

[SOURCE:
click here for more info](https://medium.com/@at15/install-nvidia-cuda-on-ubuntu-17-04-823300ab7bcc)